# Is it ok to install Zimbra on LAMP dedibox?

Tags: zimbra

Is it ok to install zimbra on LAMP dedicated server which is running only our websites (no client sites) and also mails are only ours ?

Do you see any disadvantage to install it on the same box where PHP/Apache/Mysql is running ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly recommend Zimbra have its own server.  It may be possible to get it to work, but zimbra is also using Port 80 web traffic and MySQL, so you'd have to configure it for alternate ports or bind it to a different IP address.  That will make maintenance in the future more painful.  Depending on the number of users you are supporting on Zimbra, it can also make heavy use of resources which could impact the other services running on the host.

Comment: What if I use shared hosting to handle my email needs ?

Comment: I guess that would depend on how the shared hosting is setup.  If it is basically a VM then it would be pretty much as if it were its own box.  If shared hosting is from a webserver perspective where you just have separate apache processes, that won't help this kind of scenario.  In either case you'd still have the issue of resource contention between the two.

Answer (score 0):

There's an inherent disadvantage to installing *service x* on a device whose purpose is *service y*; they can affect each other very easily.

- One service eats all the RAM?  The other service is affected.
- One service fills the disk?  The other service is affected.
- Need to restart the server or do other maintenance for something related to one service?  You might get some interesting questions about why those two things are connected.
- Security breach on one service?  All the services on the server are compromised now.

This is ultimately a business decision, but installing unrelated services on a device just because it's available and capable will, in my experience, create *many* more problems than it solves.

Comment: What if I use shared hosting to handle my email needs ?